# Can't access sculpting tools when in workspace - 2.93

Tags: interface, sculpting, workspaces

I'm just starting to learn Blender 2.93, but I can't seem to access the Sculpt workspace.  When I click on it, none of the sculpting tools appear.  When I open up a file where I was sculpting rather than doing other types of editing, this isn't a problem.  I've searched exhaustively but can't find any explanation as to why this is the case.  Thank you so much, I feel absolutely lost!

[image]

Comment: OK, I figured it out! I was trying to work with metaballs, which aren't a mesh object and therefore can't be manipulated with sculpting tools!

Answer (score 0):

You can go into Sculpt Mode manually by clicking on the interaction mode button on the top left and selecting Sculpt Mode. You can also press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> then click Sculpt Mode or press <kbd>2</kbd>. Once you've entered Sculpt Mode, you can change to another workspace and return and it will remember the last mode you were in whether it be Object/Sculpt/Edit/Texture Paint mode etc. An Object that can be sculpted must be selected to go into Sculpt Mode. Metaballs, for example, are one of the objects that cannot be sculpted.

[image]